# how to get rid of lambda syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

I need to make those function in the "normal" syntax. how do i change it?

```
template <template <class, class> class Container>
        typename const Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> >  Schedule<Container>::getAllCourses( ) const
        {
            Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> > newone;
            std::for_each(courses.begin(), courses.end(), [&newone](Course *c)
            {Course* nc = new Course(c->getName(),c->getNumber(), c->getFaculty()); newone.push_back(nc);});
            //make a container and push into it every course
            return newone;
        }
```

actually, I need to change the function "for_each" that it will use outside class.
I don't know how to do it. can you help?

Comment: You could just make the lambda into a functor exactly like the standard defines it is anyway in [expr.prim.lambda].

Comment: Have you tried to do it? Do you understand how current version of code works?

Comment: I don't really understand you. I don't know how this coude works so I would be glad to an explanation. but my teacher asked me to change this code anyway to a normal syntax.

Comment: This sounds to me like a homework/assignment related question; stackoverflow is not here to do it for you. You should do some research into lambda expressions and basic `for` loops before asking these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda function is a **closure type**, implemented as an **unnamed functor**.

You could look into those keywords, to understand how to perform a "conversion". Pretty much the rule would be that this lambda :

```
[capture_clause](args) -> return_type { /* lambda_body */ }
```

is practically (in a simplified view - generic lambdas or value/ref captures not explicitly shown here) this

```
struct no_name
{
    no_name(capture_clause) : /* Initialize the closure */ { }
    return_type operator()(args) { /* lambda_body */ }
};
```

---

In your case, you'd have to a make a class like the following :

```
template <template <class, class> class Container>
struct lamda_fun
{
    Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> > &newone;

    lamda_fun(Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> > &newone)
        : newone(newone) {
    }
    void operator()(Course *c) {
        Course* nc = new Course(c->getName(),c->getNumber(), c->getFaculty());     
        newone.push_back(nc);
    }
};
```

If you still want to get rid of the lambda syntax call it like

```
std::for_each(courses.begin(), courses.end(), lamda_fun<Container>(newone));
```

Even though a copy of the functor will be passed to `for_each`, the functor wraps a reference so the correct thing will be done.

---

An easier way would be to just use a `for` loop though (yes those still exist)

```
// range based version
for (auto c : courses) {
    Course* nc = new Course(c->getName(), c->getNumber(), c->getFaculty());     
    newone.push_back(nc);
}

// traditional version
for (auto it = courses.begin(), ite = courses.end(); it != ite; ++it) 
{
    auto c = *it;
    Course* nc = new Course(c->getName(), c->getNumber(), c->getFaculty());     
    newone.push_back(nc);
}
```

Comment: @user144555 By doing *exactly* what this answers says: create a functor that implements `operator()` correctly, then pass an instance of that functor to your algorithm. (+1, btw).

Comment: thanks! I don't know why, but the compiler says that something is wrong with the defenition of the container ("Container is not a template"). how do i fix it?

Comment: @user144555 Maybe if you posted the full code in [ideone](http://ideone.com/) I could better help you (that is if even the `for` loop version is still not clear)

Comment: The for loop version is fine but i need to use stl function (for_each). the compiler doesnt give me to run this code because it says that I need to define the container as a template (because my "getallcourses" class is a template maybe...

Comment: @user144555 Ok I edited the answer. You have to template `lambda_fun` for `Container` types and then specify the type in `for_each(..., lambda_fun<Container>())` That should do but without the code (I understand that it maybe impossible to upload the whole lot) small tweaks needed may spoil compilation.

Comment: In your picture you define a memeber named `Container` within `lamda_fun`, I assume that there is no type named `Container` and that you need to define it or make the class a class template.

Answer (score 1):

You might replace the lambda with a local class:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class Container>
Container transform(const Container& container) {

    struct Lambda {
        Container& result;
        Lambda(Container& result) : result(result) {}
        void operator () (const typename Container::value_type& value) {
            result.push_back(value + 1);
        }
    };

    Container result;
    std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), Lambda(result));
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> u;
    u.push_back(0);
    u.push_back(1);
    u.push_back(2);
    std::vector<int> v = transform(u);
    std::cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << '\n';
}
```